# trying to use getJSoN and keep getting an error

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure up something very simple, I am trying to load a json file(users.json) data and keep getting an error:

- the call is from Default.aspx

The file location:
[image: the file location]

The error:
[image: the error]

The path is wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure it's `$.getJSON()` - check your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your syntax.

Replace:

```
$.getJson("users.json", function() {
```

With:

```
$.getJSON("users.json", function(data) {
```

where `data` is your json object

---

P.S. if you get `404 - File not found` error when trying to load `.json` file in a aspx app/page, it means your IIS doesn't know how to serve the `.json` file.

Therefore, you need to modify the `Web.conf` file and add the mime type in manually, like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: did it, now i get this error: "GET http://localhost:8997/users.json 404 (Not Found) "

Comment: ok, that's a different error now. You need to provide the correct path to your file inside the `$.getJSON()` method. Check your file path.

Comment: getJSON is not deprecated?

Comment: the path is like in the image i have attached, the JSON file is in the root folder and i am calling him from default.aspx
I am wrong?

Comment: So the file is on the site root? then why are you getting an 404 - file not found?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51691/discussion-between-latheesan-kanes-and-user2487126)